# grep pattern in specific file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, glob

Let's say there is file and named with every date, like…

```
log-2021-01-01
log-2021-01-02
log-2021-01-03
...
...
log-2021-12-31
```

For example:
If we would like to find "fatal_error" during Jan,2021~Apr,2021, we could use following command:

```
#grep -E fatal_error log-2021-0[1-4]*
```

However, what if we want to find pattern during Sep,2021~Dec,2021?
Could we achieve in one command?

We've tried a few different methods but doesn't work.
Need master's advice, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest with `bash`:

```
grep fatal_error log-2021-09-* log-2021-1[0-2]-*
```

Comment: This should work with any Bourne-compatible shell (and then some).

Comment: @tripleee Under [tag:bash], there is [Brace Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537060/1765658)

Comment: Yeah, I saw your answer, but this one doesn't use any Bash features.

Comment: @F.Hauri: yes, with `bash` version >= 4.0: `grep fatal_error log-2021-{09..12}-*`

Answer (score 1):

As this question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

#### You could use ***Brace Expansion***:

This line will select files, from *`2021-10-15`* to *`2022-03-30`* (or now, as today is *`2022-03-19`*).

```
grep fatal_error log-202{1-10-{15..31},1-1[12],2-0[1-3]}*
```

#### Let's see:

```
mkdir /tmp/braceDemo
cd $_
declare -i thisday
read -r thisday < <(date -d '2020-01-01' +%s)
for ((;thisday<EPOCHSECONDS;thisday+=86400)) ;do
    printf -v file 'log-%(%F)T' $thisday
    touch $file
done
```

This will create at least 809 files, from `log-2020-01-01` to `log-$today`...

```
ls -l | sed -ne '2p;$p'
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  0 Mar 19 10:38 log-2020-01-01
-rw-r--r-- 1 user  user  0 Mar 19 10:38 log-2022-03-19

ls | wc -l
809
```

Then test:

```
printf " - %s\n" log-202{1-10-{15..31},1-1[12],2-0[1-3]}* |
    tee >(sed -ne '1p;$p' >&2) | wc -l
 - log-2021-10-15
 - log-2022-03-19
156
```

This address *`156`* files, from *`log-2021-10-15`* to *`log-2022-03-19`*.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
grep fatal_error $(for f in log-*; do [[ $f >= log-2021-09-01 && $f <= log-2021-12-31 ]] && printf '%s\n' "$f"; done)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this came up in a comment, here is a simple and portable Awk solution. The `grep` answer by Cyrus is much better for the OP's scenario, but perhaps this can help someone solve a more intricate one.

```
awk '/fatal_error/ && (FILENAME > "log-2021-09" && FILENAME < "log-2022-01")' log-*
```

This is somewhat inefficient; if your Awk supports `nextfile`, skipping to the next file (perhaps after reading the file's first line, if you want to be portable beyond GNU Awk) would potentially speed it up a lot.